# com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using IBM MQ allclient Library (9.1.0.x) with spring boot of version 2.4.x for connecting the IBM MQ. We are creating the MQConfig with these below values hostname, port, channel, user, queueManager, accessQueue.

And also we are using JMSOperations bean which is created with the CachingConnectionFactory of sessionCacheSize(500).

The issue what we are seeing is when the messages are  published to the QUEUE the below error is occurring.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'somehost'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3='somehost',4=TCP]
```

Could you please suggest how can we resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you checked what error is logged on the queue manager?